# Debug javascript template

Tags: javascript, firebug, underscore.js, google-chrome-devtools

i want to ask is there any way to debug the code written in JavaScript templates? i am using `underscore.js` for templates along with `backbone.js`.

other JavaScript code can be debugged through firebug/chrome . but i don't know how to debug a template. is it possible?

**EDIT**

```
var t ='        <div class="row-fluid">'                                                                                                          '
        +'          <div class="span12">'                                                                                                           '
        +'            <div class="span2 nowrap">'                                                                                                   '
        +'              <input class="" type="checkbox"/><%=Time%>'                                                                       '
        +'            </div>'                                                                                                                       '                                                                                                                     '
        +'        </div>'                                                                                                                          '



    TableRow = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        template:_.template(t),
        className: "",

        initialize: function (options) 
        {

        },

        render: function() 
        {
            this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
            return this;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Backbone Eye (Firebug extension), you can debug underscore templates - just as if they were regular JavaScript files. The template id (if specified) comes up in the script window (of Firefox) and you can select it (just like a regular script file), put breakpoints and watch the template being incrementally built. More details on how to do this is at http://dhruvaray.github.io/spa-eye/#views

Answer (score 0):

muneeb,
I always used firebug.
first you will need to install the plugin  after installing u will see the greyed out BUG icon towards topright section of firefox.
you can start debugging by pressing on that icon or by pressing F12 key.
There you will see tabs like
Console,HTML,CSS,Script,DOM,net,cookies.

selecting script will ask you to reload the page again so that firebug can capture the java script written.
add breakpoints and start debugging.:)

Comment: yes you can debug it too by selecting the file name from the dropdown provided for the included .js files.
if the js is minified you can also download plugin to unminify js too for debugging purpose

Comment: i have made edit. this is how i use templates. how can i check the value of time in debugger

Comment: value of time will be printed on load time you can check it but viewing it source or by inspecting the checkbox element or you can find the script variable with already prepared complete 'div'